# React button connection with database through axios.post()

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, axios

I have 4 inputs and button which takes all data from them and sends to my PostreSQL database through axios.post() request. Not clearly understand how .then() is working. So, here is my button code which just calls this.addNewPainting function:

```
<button onClick={ this.addNewPainting }>Submit</button>
```

Here is my addNewPainting function:

```
addNewPainting() {
  axios.post(`http://localhost:333/api/add`, {
    title: this.state.titleInput,
    year: this.state.yearInput,
    size: this.state.yearInput,
    location: this.state.locationInput
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Before this project, I used to put response.data to the array with this.setState, but now I have the database and I'm just stuck.

Here is my controller function:

```
add_painting: (req, res, next) => {
  const db = req.app.get('db');
  const { title, year, size, location } = req.body;
  console.log(title, year, size, location);

  db.add_painting([ title, year, size, location ])
    .then( () => res.status(200).send() )
    .then( () => res.status(500).send() );
}
```

And the endpoint:

```
app.post('/api/add', paintings_controller.add_painting);
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: DerekHopper  Yes, that's the error: Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reading (becase you requested it): I'm not an expert using `promises`, but it works similarly like the `AJAX` requests.

When you make a request to the server (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, etcetera), you're waiting for a response from this (a collection of data, a message, a succesful/unsuccesful `POST`/`PUT`/`DELETE`, etcetera). Depending of the response, you'll code the expected events (`error`, `success`, `complete`, etcetera).

In this case you're using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), a new way to do `AJAX` requests. The equivalent way of the `error`/`success`/`complete`/... events is the `then()` function. Using this approach you can perform operations that makes new tasks or simply print a response message (in your case) of the server.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

> The `then()` method returns a Promise. It takes up to two arguments:
>   callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise.

Let's suppose that we have this snippet of code in AJAX:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url : yourURL,
    type : 'POST',
    data : yourData,
    datatype : 'json',
    success : function(data) { 
        yourSuccessFunction(data); 
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        yourErrorFunction(); 
    }
});
```

Using `axios`, you'll code something like this:

```
axios.post('/user', {
    YourData: yourData
}).then(() => { this.yourSuccessFunction() })
}).catch(() => { this.yourErrorFunction() });
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found the error. I was making a request to PORT 333 in my axios.post(), but the server was working on port 3333.

Comment: I was thinking that you wanted to know how the `then()` works

Comment: Well yeah, but because I don't understand how it's working, I thought that my app is not working because of .then(). So if someone had explained the reason for using it, I'd appreciate that.

Comment: Check my answer. If you find useful my answer, vote it. If you want more examples, just tell me